# Adobe target premium click tracking (conversion tracking) manually

Tags: adobe, target

Can someone help me with the new Adobe Target Premium tool.

Is there a way to track the click conversion manually without using VES?

Currently I am using latest v60 version of mbox , I hope someone can help me on this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What happened? What did you expect to happen? Show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define an mbox and update it from the elements click handler in javascript. Then you can listen for this mbox as a conversion metric.

Sample code:

```
    // when your script loads
    mboxDefine('unused string', 'Name of the Mbox');

    ...
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#element-to-track').click(function() {
        // fire the mbox (Name of the Mbox) you can see it as a conversion metric
        mboxUpdate('Name of the Mbox');
      }
    });
```

When you click the element, you should see an ajax?mbox... request going out with the name of the mbox as request parameter.

In case you want to measure a click which routes the page to another location, don't forget to add some timeout (500ms) to the click handler, so the request has time to complete.